# Thymeleaf: How to set a list as a result of a switch statement

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf in a Spring project, and I need to show a list, as a result of a one of the cases, but I don't know how.

This is the code:

```
<!--Global validation results-->
<div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('global')}">
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"
        th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('global')}">

   <div th:switch="${err}">
      <div th:case="error.fromAfterTo" th:text="#{error.fromAfterTo}"></div>
      <div th:case="error.overlaps" th:text="#{error.overlaps}">

         <ul th:each="interval : ${dateOverlaps}">
            <li th:text="${#temporals.format(interval.datefrom, 'dd/MM/yyyy')} +
              ' - ' + ${#temporals.format(interval.dateto, 'dd/MM/yyyy')}">                                                    
            </li>
         </ul>

      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

th:case="error.overlaps" works, but the list just appears, when setting it outside the switch statement.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Aleix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `th:text` attribute, which evaluates `#{error.overlaps}`sets the result of this evaluation as the body of the `div` tag it is in, effectively substituting your loop with the evaluation result. That is why you see the list outside of the switch.

Details [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#using-thtext-and-externalizing-text).

Comment: Thanks a lot @LachezarBalev, the key was to take out the th:text="#{error.overlaps}", from the case statement.

Answer (score 0):

can you substitute

```
th:case="error.overlaps"
```

with

```
th:case="#{error.overlaps}"
```

and let me know if this worked for you

Comment: No, it didn't work.
I've added some code to complete the validation section.
Thanks @Periklis

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code, that's working as expected:

```
<!--Global validation results-->
<div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('global')}">
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"
        th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('global')}"> 
        <div th:switch="${err}">
            <div th:case="error.fromAfterTo" th:text="# error.fromAfterTo}"></div>
            <div th:case="error.overlaps">
               <p th:text="#{error.overlaps}"></p>
               <ul th:each="interval : ${dateOverlaps}">
                  <li th:text="${#temporals.format(interval.datefrom, 'dd/MM/yyyy')} 
                      + ' - ' + ${#temporals.format(interval.dateto, 'dd/MM/yyyy')}">                                                    
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
   </div>
</div><!--Global validation results-->
```

Thanks once more for your help.